# Using swapfile and swap partition

Tags: swap

I have a couple of Ubuntu 16.04LTS servers running in a VMWare cluster. They were originally set up with a 1GB swap partition. I had a problem with OOM exceptions, which were solved by increasing the RAM and adding a swapfile. The servers now have the original swap partition and the swapfile.

Here's the output from swapon --summary

```
#swapon --summary
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-3                               partition       1043964 55456   -1
/swapfile                               file            16777212        0       -2
```

Is it a good idea to have both a swap partition and a swapfile?

99% of the time the server doesn't touch the swapfile, but occasionally when the load is really high it uses the swapfile and the partition. I'd grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: using zram along with a swap file or swap partition might be better

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about trying zram. I will give it go.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable to have both, I've been doing that frequently in the past. Now that I have machine with larger RAM and SSD, there's no need for swap partition, though I do use swap files

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with that, but you can delete your swap partition and use swapfile only.
Don't forget to add your swapfile in /etc/fstab file.

Answer (score 0):

No problem =)

Just **put your Swap partition UUID in the file** and also you must also **activate it via Gparted**, although they don't tell it. Both installation parts don't do the same things, as they are steps. Instructions are on: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

My Ubuntu Studio 18.04 LTS is running in a normal computer just for it =) And it has both swap file and swap partition, created after OS installation with `Gparted` DVD from outside then with `Gparted` software package from inside, so needs complete activation.

```
$ sudo swapon --all --verbose
swapon: /swapfile : déjà active — ignorée
swapon: /dev/sda4 : déjà active — ignorée
$  swapon --summary
Nom de fichier              Type        Taille  Utilisé Priorité
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
/dev/sda4                               partition   41469948    0   -3
$ cat /proc/swaps
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
/dev/sda4                               partition   41469948    0   -3
```

With big computers, although there isn't much use except for 3D and Video creation, more it's fast, better it is =) Also I read it's even faster to begin with Swap partition, but you will break the system if Ubuntu is already installed.

So if you start a brand new OS or Server or Virtual Machine, you can add the Swap partition before all partitions. But if not don't move anything as it could break the grub or the boot. And anyway, 2 swap methods, with `sda 1` to `sda4` in right order, is already good enough. =)